# How to add a .ttf font file from web in SASS to be displayed in HAML

Tags: html, sass

```
@font-face
  font-family: MyFont
  src: url(https://.../font_name.ttf?raw=true)

$font-main: 'MyFont' , sans-serif

.some_class
font-family: $font-main
```

When I use MyFont coming from web there is no effect. How to do this properly?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't need to add a `.ttf`, simply include the font `@import` url at the top in your main `.scss` file:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Overpass');
```

Then to use it:

```
//store it in variable first
$font-main: 'Overpass', sans-serif;
//to use it   
.selector {
   font-family: $font-main;
}
```

This would be best for browser compatibility.

---

If for whatever reason you still want to load a `.ttf` file, in your sass file at the top set it's name and path:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'myFont';
   src: url("fonts/myFont.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

then use it:

```
$font-main: 'myFont', sans-serif;
.selector {
    font-family: $font-main;
}
```

---

**Demo Snippet 1** - loading font via conventional CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Overpass');
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Overpass');
div {
  font-family: 'Overpass', sans-serif;
}
span {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div>Overpass font loaded</div>
<span>regular sans-serif</span>
```

---

**Demo Snippet 2** - loading font via HTML in-between your `<head></head>` tags:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Overpass" rel="stylesheet">
```

```css
div {
  font-family: 'Overpass', sans-serif;
}
span {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Overpass" rel="stylesheet">
<div>Overpass font loaded</div>
<span>regular sans-serif</span>
```

Demonstration font was taken [from here](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Overpass)

Comment: I need to use .ttf file, because it is not standard font. Also this @font-face is not working. Editor returns:

`Invalid CSS after "": expected selector, was "}"`

Comment: robo0477, you must be doing something wrong. I updated the answer by removing unnecessary examples and included a .ttf one from MDN @font-face, make sure you include quotes when storing in variable `$font-main: 'myFont', sans-serif;` - hope helps.

Comment: You are right. It seems like there is problem with getting this .ttf file from web.

Comment: It didn't solve my problem if that is what you are asking. It works fine with local files, but not with the ones in web.