# Using font awesome ttf with scss

Tags: css, sass, font-awesome

I'm trying to use font awesome with scss.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'awesome';
  src: url('../../fonts/font-awesome/fa-light-300.ttf') format('ttf');
}
```

the path seems to be correct but i'm getting errors:
Failed to compile.

> ./src/assets/styles/main.scss
> (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-3-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-3-3!./src/assets/styles/main.scss)
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
> '../../fonts/font-awesome/fa-light-300.ttf' in
> 'C:\Users\idogo\Desktop\‏‏תיקיה חדשה\sprint-4\src\assets\styles'

I hope you can help me,
thanks

Comment: So you don't really [need to declare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41747557/how-to-add-a-ttf-font-file-from-web-in-sass-to-be-displayed-in-haml/41747690) like that with a `ttf` file but your error is just telling you the file path is incorrect. Can you confirm the `/fonts/font-awesome/...` exists in `C:\Users\idogo\Desktop\‏‏תיקיה חדשה\sprint-4\src\assets\styles` directory? If not just need to modify your path.

Comment: Ok, so go back a couple more directories in your path like `url('../../../../fonts/ `  or correct wherever the import being set for `\src\assets\styles` to, or move the `fonts` folder into the `\src\assets\styles\` directory. Either way the goal is just for it to find the file from where you're referencing it from.

Comment: the full directory is: `C:\Users\idogo\Desktop\‏‏תיקיה חדשה\sprint-4\src\assets\fonts\font-awesome\fa-light-300.ttf`

Answer (score 0):

Appernetly all i needed is to add ~@ at the begining of the path.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'awesome';
  src: url('~@/fonts/font-awesome/fa-light-300.ttf') format('ttf');
}
```